# Unable to browserify a hello world using AWS-SDK

Tags: npm, browserify, aws-sdk-js

I am new to browserify and npm so I could be doing something wrong but it seems like this should work.  On a mac, running Big Sur, npm version 8.1.3:

```
mkdir test
cd test
npm init
npm install @aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2
```

create `index.js` in that directory and add this content to it:

```
const { LexRuntimeV2Client, DeleteSessionCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2");
console.log("test" + LexRuntimeV2Client)
```

If you run using node, it works fine:

```
$ node index.js 
testclass LexRuntimeV2Client extends smithy_client_1.Client {
    constructor(configuration) {
        const _config_0 = runtimeConfig_1.getRuntimeConfig(configuration);
        const _config_1 = config_resolver_1.resolveRegionConfig(_config_0);
        const _config_2 = config_resolver_1.resolveEndpointsConfig(_config_1);
        const _config_3 = middleware_retry_1.resolveRetryConfig(_config_2);
        const _config_4 = middleware_host_header_1.resolveHostHeaderConfig(_config_3);
        const _config_5 = middleware_signing_1.resolveAwsAuthConfig(_config_4);
        const _config_6 = middleware_eventstream_1.resolveEventStreamConfig(_config_5);
        const _config_7 = middleware_user_agent_1.resolveUserAgentConfig(_config_6);
        const _config_8 = eventstream_serde_config_resolver_1.resolveEventStreamSerdeConfig(_config_7);
        super(_config_8);
        this.config = _config_8;
        this.middlewareStack.use(middleware_retry_1.getRetryPlugin(this.config));
        this.middlewareStack.use(middleware_content_length_1.getContentLengthPlugin(this.config));
        this.middlewareStack.use(middleware_host_header_1.getHostHeaderPlugin(this.config));
        this.middlewareStack.use(middleware_logger_1.getLoggerPlugin(this.config));
        this.middlewareStack.use(middleware_signing_1.getAwsAuthPlugin(this.config));
        this.middlewareStack.use(middleware_user_agent_1.getUserAgentPlugin(this.config));
    }
    destroy() {
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

If you try to browserfy you get:

```
$ browserify index.js > indexBundle.js
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/ericzinda/test/process'
    required by /Users/ericzinda/test/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-user-agent-node/dist-cjs/index.js
```

Am I doing something wrong here?